# Fine-uploader in iOS and iPad

Tags: fine-uploader

I checked if fineuploader worked on an iPad, and it does mostly, but the iPad only gets a single file "image.jpg" returned, so every file that's uploaded keeps overwriting the previous file.  (Or it just uploads one file)
In any case, can this behavior be fixed on either Chrome or Safari on an iPad?

We are using library to uploaded images for different business requirement and its works like dream. thanks for developing this one.

Krishna

here is my code:

I am creating endpoint dynamically and uploading files for different folders. Its getting uploaded for other platform except iOS.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#s3-fileuploader').fineUploader({
        request: {
            endpoint: '',
            inputName: 'filename',
            forceMultipart: true,
            paramsInBody: true,
            params: {},
        },
        failedUploadTextDisplay: {
            mode: 'custom',
            maxChars: 40,
            responseProperty: 'error',
            enableTooltip: true
        },
        cors: {
            expected: true, //all requests are expected to be cross-domain requests
            sendCredentials: false, //if you want cookies to be sent along with the request
            allowXdr: true
        },
        autoUpload: true,
        multiple: true,
        debug: true,
        text: {
            uploadButton: '<i class="icon-plus icon-white">Select Files</i> '
        },
        deleteFile: {
            enabled: false,
            forceConfirm: true,
        },
        validation: {
            // allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
            itemLimit: 75
        }
    }).on('submit', function (event, id, name) {
        $(this).fineUploader('setEndpoint', endPoint); //set endpoint
    }).on('complete', function (event, id, fileName, response) {
        var $deleteEl = $(
            '<span class="delete">&#160;&#160;<a href="javascript:;" onclick="deleteFile(\'' +
            response.deleteFileUrl + '\',\'' + id +
            '\')">Delete</a></span>&#160;&#160;');
        //when you delete element is clicked, call the "deleteFile" API method, passing in that file's ID
        if (response.success) {
            $(".qq-uploader").append(
                '<div class="highlight" style="margin-top:8px;margin-right:8px;float:left;width:180px;height:194px; box-shadow:1px 0 0 #F3F3F3, 0 1px 0 #E4E4E4, 0 -1px 0 #F3F3F3, -1px 0 0 #F3F3F3" class="thumb" id="thumb_' +
                id + '"></div>');
            //get file name from responce
            var filename = getFileName(response.getThumbnailUrl);
            //get file extension now
            var fileExt = filename.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
            //create array of all available extenions images
            var exts = ["csv", "doc", "docx", "xls", "zip", "pdf",
                "txt"
            ];
            //check if its a image
            if (fileExt == 'jpeg' || fileExt == 'jpg' || fileExt ==
                'png' || fileExt == 'gif' || fileExt == 'tiff' ||
                fileExt == 'tif' || fileExt == 'bmp' || fileExt ==
                'wbmp') {
                //myother logic
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the design of iOS, not Fine Uploader. See, iOS names the files for you -- "image.jpg" to be exact.

Fine Uploader mitigates this problem by generating a level 4 UUID and sending that along with the upload request. The parameter to look for in the request body is `qquuid`.

I'm guessing your server is saving files based on their filename only. A more robust solution would be to use a combination of the file's UUID and filename to ensure users are not overwriting files that already exist.

Your server could prepend the UUID to the filename:

`4A0BC570-0125-11E3-B778-0800200C9A66_image.jpg`

or create an entirely new folder:

`4A0BC570-0125-11E3-B778-0800200C9A66/image.jpg`

Not only will this ensure that users uploading on iOS don't overwrite each others' files, but it will also ensure that two users on *any* platform uploading two different files with the same name won't step on each others' toes.

If you have any server-/client-side code you'd like to share, I can take a peek, modify it and post in here with my answer.

Comment: I am using this cors and uploading images to aws s3 and I am creating endpoint dynamically and uploading files to different folders. its working fine in all the browsers even in safari its working fine.       
          request: {
                        endpoint: '',
                        inputName: 'filename',
                        forceMultipart: true,
                        paramsInBody : true,
                              },
           cors: {
                expected: true, 
                sendCredentials: false,
                allowXdr: true
            },

Comment: @krishnaBhatt sendCredentials is false by default, forceMultipart is true by default as is paramsInBody. No need to set those values.  Also, if you are not using the deleteFile feature, why are you setting allowXdr to true?

Comment: I am using delete feature. as we are not using UUID to create files on the server hence not sending that to server also. hence I could not use delete feature of fine-uploader so created own jquery delete function.  as we are using this with cloudbees java app and sending our most of parameters in query string...is this UUID need to be there for ios upload or we can handle it other way also?

Comment: The UUID does not **need** to be there, but know that your iOS users will be overwriting each others' files if it is not. Just think about it, you need some sort of psuedo-random name per file to ensure that your users are not saving files of the same name and overwriting each others' uploads. The UUID is provided for you by Fine Uploader to mitigate this problem.

Comment: I might be having a different issue, but it sure sounds like the same one and only affects iOS. And it has nothing to do with the filenames being the same, instead what happens is that when I upload an image it gets added to the list of images, when I then upload a new image (clicking the same upload button again), the first image disappears. So the list never contains more than one image. Again, this is _only_ in iOS. In Android/Windows/Whatever every new image gets added to list as expected.